# How to I read in the body content in .net core 3.0?

Tags: .net-core-3.0

I am upgrading my solution from .net core 2.2 to 3.0, and I want to log the request data/body in the "proper" way. I am reading a lot that using the PipeReader is preferred to reading directly from the stream.

Previous to .net core 3.0, we used streams and the EnableRewind() method. It looked something like this:

```
HttpRequest.EnableRewind();
HttpRequest.Body.Position = 0;
var sr = new StreamReader(HttpRequest.Body);
var myData = sr.ReadToEnd();
HttpRequest.Body.Position = 0;
return myData;
```

I would like to understand how to properly use the PipeReader. Eg. what code is necessary to read in the HttpRequest body into a string? I see there is a ReadAsync() and TryRead() methods, but I'm not sure how to properly use these. I also see there is an AsStream() method which I've been able to use on the stream as I previously had (but without rewind).

I'd love to see any examples on how to do this, because it seems as though working with the pipe requires a great deal of pointer references. Lastly, if I work with the PipeReader.AsStream(), do I need to worry about rewind?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you find a solution for it? If yes, please share!

Comment: Nope, still can't find any information on how this is supposed to work :(

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it:

```
        HttpRequest.EnableBuffering();
        using var streamReader = new StreamReader(HttpRequest.Body);
        string data = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
```

`EnableBuffering()` replaces `EnableRewind()`.

Comment: I did see about the EnableBuffering(), looks like you're using the StreamReader method as well. I've updated by code to basically be the same as yours, except for passing some additional arguments to the StreamReader: HttpRequest.Body, Encoding.UTF8, false, 1024, true;
What I'm curious about is if this is still the preferred way of doing things - or if the PipeReader is preferred (and if so, how).